# 2 Files to compare with columns

Tags: sorting, awk, grep

I have got 2 files and need an output

```
file 1 column 1 == file 2 column 1 > output
file 1 column 1 =! file 2 column 1 [Remove]
```

file 1 contains 2 columns

file 2 only 1

So if the first column from file 1 is the same as file 2 then it needs to output the 2 columns from file 1.

example file 1=

```
Cheese:12
Bloom:13
Kitkat:3478
```

File 2=

```
Cheese
Kitkat
```

Output=

```
Cheese:12
Kitkat:3478
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as selecting lines in `file 1` from `file 2`, then with `grep`:

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

Output:

```
Cheese:12
Kitkat:3478
```

Comment: It would need to work for windows and awk isn’t doing that I do use Cygwin if you want

Comment: @SoSander: you have `grep` in Cygwin. There was an error in my code, the `-v` option shouldn't have been there. Updated the answer.